# An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with PrimaryKey when trying to create an entity without any special database orders

Tags: android, entity, android-room

I have the following Entity in my project -

```java
@Entity(tableName = "query_table")
public class QueryModel {


    public String ID;

    private String vendorName;

    private String productName;

    private String lateTimeUpdated;

    public QueryModel(@NonNull String ID, String vendorName, String productName, String lateTimeUpdated) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.lateTimeUpdated = lateTimeUpdated;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getVendorName() {
        return vendorName;
    }

    public void setVendorName(String vendorName) {
        this.vendorName = vendorName;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getLateTimeUpdated() {
        return lateTimeUpdated;
    }

    public void setLateTimeUpdated(String lateTimeUpdated) {
        this.lateTimeUpdated = lateTimeUpdated;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is an entity that receives it's values entirely from the server, meaning I do not need any auto increment of anything - I will take care of this entity myself.

But when trying to start my app with this following class I get the error -

`An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey`

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's necessary to put @PrimaryKey annotation and btw it will not auto increment this column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data) you should define a primary key using annotation @PrimaryKey

```
@PrimaryKey
public int id;
```

or, another example like this

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"firstName", "lastName"})
public class User {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

Comment: alright, after resolving this issue and fixing it to int value with PrimaryKey I got the following error - `UNIQUE constraint failed: query_table.ID ` - what am I missing?

Comment: You'll have to make sure that ID field is unique, otherwise it cannot be a primarykey